# Nested loop: what is the output? How to find it?

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

```
public class NestedLoop{

public static void main(String args[]){
   int total=0;
   for(int i=0;i<=8;i+=2){
       for(int j=i;j>=0;j-=2){
           total= total+i;
       }
   }
   System.out.print(total);
  }
```

}

How to find the output of the "total"? How to approach this type of problem? What's the easiest way to approach it?

Comment: Try to simulate it on paper ;)

Comment: Paper and a pencil would probably the most easy approach.

Comment: this is an infinite loop. here `for(int j=i;i>+0;j-=2)` you have the condition with i but decrease j

Comment: Have you tried running this? What does the System.out.print(total) line do?

Comment: You have already printed the output of total. Are you not getting any output?

Comment: How to approach this type of problem? what type?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote the wrong code. Just edited it

Answer (score 0):

this is an infinite loop. here `for(int j=i;i>+0;j-=2)` you have the condition with i but decrease j. therefore you won't get any output ever. to get an output, use this code:

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i += 2) {
    for (int j = i; j > 0; j -= 2) {
        total = total + i;
    }
}
System.out.print(total);
```

if you mean with this `i>+0` that it should be always bigger than 0 you can also leave out the `+`. if it was a typo, change it to `j>=0`